# How to change a list of list into a normal list

Tags: python-3.x

I have two lists:

```
list1 = ['apples','chicken',['apple juice', 'organge juice']]
list2 = ['oranges','beef',['milk','soda']]
```

my goal is to combine the two lists into a third list which I have accomplished using:

```
temp_list = [list(a) for a in zip(list1, list2)]
```

the output becomes:

```
[['apples', 'oranges'], ['chicken', 'beef'], [['apple juice', 'orange juice'], ['milk', 'soda']]]
```

However, for the third entry of the list, I do not want it to create sublists within the entry so I want the output to look like:

```
 [['apples', 'oranges'], ['chicken', 'beef'], ['apple juice', 'orange juice','milk', 'soda']
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:-

```
def return_list(list1, list2):
    temp = []

    for i in range(len(list1)):
        if (isinstance(list1[i], list) and isinstance(list2[i], list)):
            temp.append(list1[i]+list2[i])
        elif isinstance(list1[i], list) and not isinstance(list2[i], list):
            temp.append(list1[i]+[list2[i]])
        elif isinstance(list2[i], list) and not isinstance(list1[i], list):
            temp.append([list1[i]]+list2[i])
        else:
            temp.append([list1[i]]+[list2[i]])

    return temp
```

Output -

```
[['apples', 'oranges'], ['chicken', 'beef'], ['apple juice', 'organge juice', 'milk', 'soda']]
```

Comment: Hi, this doesnt appear to work if there are different sized sublists. for example if list1 was [['apples','bananas'],'chicken',['apple juice', 'orange juice']]
any idea how to do it for lists with different sized sublists?

Comment: @dkcode I have updated the code. Now the above-mentioned problem is solved. You can try it now.